# code that wont work after other code executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, game-development

I am working on a game for a class and there is some code that won't execute  if I execute another part of the code sorry this problem is hard to explain but I would like to get some help. I will link the fiddle here so you can see the code in action https://jsfiddle.net/Gamebit/96mLcfxw/

this is the code that won't work

```
//this is the code that wont work 
    if(moveKey.key === 'a'){

    $("#bidenHead").animate({marginLeft: "+250px"}, 500, function(){});

    $("#body").animate({marginLeft: "+295px"}, 565, function(){});

    $("#leftArm").animate({marginLeft: "+268px"}, 645, function(){});

    $("#rightArm").animate({marginLeft: "+323px"}, 450, function(){});

    $("#rightLeg").animate({marginLeft: "+328px"}, 625, function(){});

    $("#leftLeg").animate({marginLeft: "+260px"}, 450, function(){}); 
     }
     //if I execute this code the above wont execute
  if(moveKey.key === 'd') {
    $("#bidenHead").animate({right: "250px"}, 500, function(){});

    $("#body").animate({right: "295px"}, 565, function(){});

    $("#leftArm").animate({right: "322px"}, 645, function(){});

    $("#rightArm").animate({right: "267px"}, 450, function(){});

    $("#rightLeg").animate({right: "260px"}, 625, function(){});

    $("#leftLeg").animate({right: "330px"}, 450, function(){}); 
     }
  })
```

heres the css if you need it

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 510px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.stickBody {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 556px;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.stickArmLeft {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 528px;
  margin-top: 300px;

}

.stickArmRight {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 585px;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.stickLegLeft {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 522px;
  margin-top: 385px;
}

.stickLegRight {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 590px;
  margin-top: 385px;
}

p1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

p2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
}

p3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 1056px;
}

p4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 370px;
  left: 1045px;
}
```

Comment: If it does execute by itself, you should probably include the other code that's executing that makes this not work. What have you done to debug? Is there an error in the console? What is `move.key` when this doesn't run?

Comment: I have done everything I can think of I am a new developer so that isn't much though also sorry move.key is the name of the function I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for "a" is executing it's just that the "marginLeft" property doesn't move the figure.

If you replaced it with using the "right" property like you do with "d", but with different offsets like how you use the "top" property in "w" and "s" then it will work like you intended.

There are probably better ways to handle moving the figure, but that is the issue you are seeing.

Comment: thank you so much I will get to doing this and tell you the results

Comment: this worked like a charm sorry i didn't respond quick I got side tracked

Comment: No problem, but I would appreciate it if you could mark this as the solution.

Comment: opp sorry about that